# Mirroring method in C#

Tags: methods, reflection

Is there any ways I could use, to mirror any method from another class?
i.e.

```
public class MyMethods
{

    public static double Func_1
    {


    }
    public static double Func_2
    ....
    ....
    ....

}





public class Reflector
{
    // any call to this class, should be redirected to MyMethods
    public SOMETHING_AUTOLOADER_OR_LIKE_THAT{
        ...
    }

}
```

as i could dynamically call `Reflector.Func_888();` , and if that method is not found there, then it should search in `MyMethods` and execute that .

Comment: You could maybe Inherit from `DynamicObject` and then within overload of  `TryInvokeMember` forward calls to  `MyMethods` when they don't exist but that's going to involve `dynamic` and the DLR

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 thanks, but without example, i am new to C#, and dont understand well, what you mean. If you post a full answer and it helps, i will choose the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on my phone or I would. Basically DynamicObject class intercepts calls to method invocations, property sets/gets etc and let's you decide what to do if the associated member doesn't exist. It involves the use of the dynamic keyword at the call site which also means it involves the DLR at runtime (which can hurt performance if you're concerned with that). Some examples at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx